# Example of not irreducible polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

**Hi,everyone**

If $p$ is an irreducible polynomial and $fg\equiv 0$ $\mbox{mod}$ p, show that $f\equiv 0$ 
$\mbox {mod}$ p or $g\equiv 0$ $\mbox {mod}$ p. Give an example to show that this is false if p is not irreducible.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My idea is that you write down the simplest reducible polynomial you can think of, and then the simplest non-trivial $f$ and $g$ whose product is divisible by that reducible polynomial, and see whether that doesn't give you the example you want in the second part of the question.

Comment: For the first part, the way to do it depends on what facts you have already learned about the topic.

Comment: You can take $p=fg$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ p\nmid f,\,\ p\mid fg,pg\:\Rightarrow\:p\mid (fg,pg)= (f,p)g = g,\:$ since the gcd $\rm\:(f,p) = 1\:$ (else it would be a *proper* factor of $\rm\,f,\,$ contra $\rm\,f\,$ irreducible).

You can also do the same proof replacing the gcd by its linear Bezout representation, if that seems clearer to you. That gcds (and Bezout identities) exist follows from the fact that polynomials over a field have a (Euclidean) division algorithm, analogous to that for integers.

Alternatively, if you know that $\rm\,K[x]\,$ is a UFD, then, by unique factorization, it is clear that irreducibles $\rm\:p\:$ are prime, i.e. if $\rm\:p\:$ divides a product then it divides some factor.

For the second part: reducibles $\rm\:p = fg\:$ are never prime since $\rm\ fg\mid fg,\,\  fg\nmid f,\,\ fg\nmid g.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens if $fg = 0 \bmod p$ but $f\neq 0\bmod p$ and $g\neq 0 \bmod p.$  This says that $p$ divides $f,g$ but does not divide $f$ and does not divide $g.$  Think about the possible degrees of the polynomials and you should come up with a proof of the statement.

Comment: Note that you cannot prove it only from a degree argument. It requires use of the Euclidean/division algorithm or some equivalent property of $\rm\:K[x].\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The ring of polynomials is a [UFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).